# How to test the return values of methods/queries called inside a method under test in unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

The method under test has parts like this.

```
public bool Method1()
{
 var List=Engine.GetList(id);//engine is from business layer
 var List1 = list.where(x=>x.id== id);
 var List2 = list.where(x=> x.score > 400);
 
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 m_content1 = GetContent(list1,sb);

 StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
 m_content2 = GetContent(list2,sb2);
          

}
```

GetContent is in the same class. This was written by someone else.
I feel its imperative have to  add  if statements  for checks on potential empty lists  and null string builder  in the method since they are return values that can break the case. And then  add unit test cases for these ifs in the unit test.

The key question is to figure out how to test the lists and stringbuilders  for empty/null cases.

Comment: There are too many unknowns in the provided example to be able to provide a focused answer. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Also the main question stated is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: Eliminating code for simplicity is fine, however you should still keep your example understandable.. please show more code such as bool variable you return and code using lists/StringBuilder

Comment: Updated the answer as requested. Hope all info is clear now.

Comment: Yet another effort is required, please write code that compiles